# AS3: Call function from one class to another

Tags: actionscript-3, class

So i have two Class's **Class A** and **Class B**.

I have a function that i wish to use on **Class A** but my flash fla file is linked to **Class B**

So I have done the following:

*Class A - the function*

```
    public function Fb_Checks()
    {
        // constructor code
        load_top_bar();
    }
```

*Class B - import*

```
import ClassA;
```

then if i try to call the function in Class A from Class B:

```
Fb_Checks();
```

I get the following error:

> Call to a possibly undefined method Fb_Checks.

Is there something more i should be doing to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get more info about the OOP. How it is working then it will be easier to understand concepts.

For now simple explanation: We have **ClassA**, **ClassB** and **ClassC**:

```
ClassA
{
    var value:ClassB;

    public function ClassA ()
    {
        // each variable needs to initialize unless it is the ClassC, see below
        // Only after that you will be able to reach the public properties
        // of the class.
        value = new ClassB();
        value.calculate();
    }
}

ClassB
{
    var value:Number;

    public function ClassB ()
    {

    }

    public function calculate():void
    {
        // these must be statis
        ClassC.sum(150, 450);
    }
}

ClassC
{
    // if the function is static, then you can call it without initializing
    // the class
    static public function sum(value1:Number, value2:Number):Number
    {
        return value1 + value2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to make an instance of ClassA before you can call its public functions.

```
package  
{
    import ClassA;

    public class ClassB
    {

        public function ClassB()
        {
            var instanceOfA:ClassA = new ClassA();

            instanceOfA.Fb_Checks();
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to make it work like your example you should extend your ClassB with the ClassA. In that case it's public and protected functions are available in ClassB as well.

```
package  
{
    import ClassA;

    public class ClassB extends ClassA 
    {

        public function ClassB()
        {
            Fb_Checks();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So i would like it to work like your bottom example apart from ClassB already extends 'MovieClip' and you can't multiply extends can you?

Comment: Nope you can't, but if ClassA extends MovieClip, ClassB will inherit MovieClip as well

Comment: Yes you can: `ClassA extends MovieClip` and `ClassB extends ClassA`. And `ClassB` will be able to access all of the `public`, `protected` and `internal` functions from both `ClassA` and `MovieClip`.

Comment: @JevgenijDmitrijev So this has worked but now all of the functions that access things on main frame from ClassA are getting this error: `Access of undefined property` I know why this is happening is because for example its looking for a MC called photo but thats not on this frame (or even in the same fla file) but it should it be checking the functions even if they are not being called?

Comment: Normaly if your `ClassA` calls some functions on it's own, and `ClassB` extends the `ClassA`, then all of the functions which `ClassA` is calling will be automatically be called on `ClassB` initialization.